# How does Blocking I/O operation works in a multithreaded C++ application?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have a very specific question.

1. How does blocking I/O operation e.g. recvfrom() call work in a
   multithreaded application?
2. How does the OS schedule a thread that has blocking syscalls?
3. Would    the OS schedule the thread when the blocking system call is
   executed    (e.g. similar to busy wait?) or would the OS only
   schedule the thread    once the syscall has returned?
4. Would that cause an interrupt to the executing the thread (If that is the
   case would it worthwhile to code    the critical sections of the
   other threads within a mutex or some sort of atomic operations?)

Comment: where is that question very specific?

Comment: Which OS? (comment not long enough)

Comment: @gurka has a point. For example, under Linux threads are pretty much handled like processes when it comes to scheduling. That might look a little different on Windows, and might look a lot different on something like OSes that run on microcontrollers without a MMU.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers. I was actually referring to Linux OS only.

Answer (score 2):

> How does blocking I/O operation e.g. recvfrom() call work in a
>       multithreaded application?

The thread is blocked, the others continue to be scheduled. That is one of the main advantages of developing multithreaded applications, even on single core machines.

> How does the OS schedule a thread that has blocking syscalls?

Not, until the syscall returns.

> Would the OS schedule the thread when the blocking system call is executed (e.g. similar to busy wait?) or would the OS only schedule the thread once the syscall has returned?

The first, what should the thread do while it's in the syscall?

Generally, also the latter *would* be possible, but it would be a very strange implementation, to say the least, of scheduling. In fact, assume you're the scheduler, so you're currently in kernel space. Execution of the thread is currently *not* in user space, as it waits for the syscall to return. So where would the thread "continue" to execute?

> Would that cause an interrupt to the executing the thread (If that is the case would it worthwhile to code the critical sections of the other threads within a mutex or some sort of atomic operations?)

Well, that is what a blocking call does: halt the execution till the blocking condition has passed.

Comment: I have headache even trying to imagine how would scheduler schedule a thread blocked in syscall. If it is blocked in syscall, it means it is in kernel and waiting on something. What would it mean for kernel to schedule it?

Comment: @SergeyA: exactly my point with the "strange implementation": you could set up your syscall interface in a matter that sets the execution pointer for that thread to something that immediately yields back to kernel space, but that would be oh-so-performance-lossy.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers.